# $in operator not working in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I'm trying to make a discover page for a social media website. The discover page queries the database for all posts that satisfy  four things:

1. User has not already liked post
2. Post tags do not violate user's filtered tag content
3. Post text content does not violate user's filtered post content

And finally the part of the aggregation giving me trouble:

4. Post tagIds contain a given tagId from user (a post using the same tag that the user already follows)

Here's the function:

```
const asyncFetchTagPosts = async (
  query,
  //here's a given tag that a user already follows
  tagId, 
  likedPostIds,
  Post,
  User, 
  mongoose,
  handleFilterTagRegex,
  handleFilterPostContentRegex
) => {
  var recastTagId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(tagId)

  var user = await User.findOne({ blogName: query })
  
  var filteredTagRegex = handleFilterTagRegex(user)

  var filteredPostContentRegex = handleFilterPostContentRegex(user)
  
  var posts = await Post.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'posts',
        let: {
          likedPostIds: likedPostIds,
          tagId: recastTagId,
          filteredTagRegex: filteredTagRegex,
          filteredPostContentRegex: filteredPostContentRegex
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $not: { $in: ["$_id", "$$likedPostIds"] } },
                  { $not: [
                      {
                        $regexMatch: {
                          input: "$tagTitles",
                          regex: "$$filteredTagRegex"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  { $not: [
                      {
                        $regexMatch: {
                          input: "$allText",
                          regex: "$$filteredPostContentRegex"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  { $or: [
                       //here's the bad expression, $tagIds won't resolve to an array
                      { $in: [ "$$tagId", "$tagIds" ] },
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: 'posts'
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$posts' },
    { $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": "$posts" } },
    { $sort: { "notesHeatLastTwoDays": -1 } },
    { $limit: 5 }
  ])
  return posts
}
```

Here's the Post model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const options = { discriminatorKey: 'kind' }

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  allText: {
    type: String
  },
  descriptions: [
    {
      kind: String,
      content: String,
      displayIdx: Number
    }
  ],
  descriptionImages: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Image'
    }
  ],
  tagIds: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Tag'
    }
  ],
  tagTitles: {
    type: String
  },
  mentions: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Mention'
    }
  ],
  notesCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  notesHeatLastTwoDays: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  kind: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Post'
  }
}, options)
  
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema, 'posts')

export default Post;
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing

When I comment out the last part of the query the aggregation works. It returns data in this shape:

```
{
   _id: 60c18ee43730198901cfae9b,
   descriptionImages: [],
   //here's the array I'm trying to get to resolve in the aggregation
   tagIds: [],
   mentions: [],
   notesCount: 1,
   notesHeatLastTwoDays: 0,
   kind: 'VideoPost',
   descriptions: [],
   createdAt: 2021-06-10T04:02:44.744Z,
   updatedAt: 2021-06-11T08:51:38.166Z,
   user: 608f213bb4a094bd91e02936,
   videoLink: 60c3241a6c9ed4d1fc908270,
   allText: '',
   __v: 1,
   tagTitles: ''
},
```

I thought using the `$` operator in the aggregation gave me access to each document, does it just not work if you try to use the variable as the first expression?

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle missing "$tagIds" by setting it to empty array []

```
{
   $ifNull: [
      "$tagIds",
      []
   ]
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

so you pipeline stage would be

```
{ $or: [
         //here's the bad expression, $tagIds won't resolve to an array  
          { $in: [ "$$tagId", { $ifNull: [ "$tagIds", [] ] } ] },
       ]
}
```